# Copying Multiple Subfolders to New Location with Same Layout (XP DOS)

Tags: file, loops, copy, cmd, windows-xp

Alright all here at stackoverflow

I've frequently visited this site and always found what I was looking for.  Unfortunately I think I am in a bit over my head on this one.  So I made an account and hopefully you guys will either tell me this is possible and how, or tell me I'm crazy and I will move on. =]

So here is what I want to do,
I have an old computer with several users that log on to it.  I have a new computer now and I wanted to copy the users Desktop items and Favorite items to a remote server so that I can copy them back once the new computer is set up.  The current system is XP and the new one will be win7.

I'm looking to complete this using DOS commands in a batch file.  I have some programming background, but I'm running into errors and CMD.exe isn't the greatest programming environment for troubleshooting.  This is what I have so far,

```
 FOR /R "C:\Documents and Settings\" %%G in (.) DO (
  Pushd %%G
  FOR /f %%D in (%%G\Desktop) do (
   if exist %%D\*.* COPY 
   %%D\*.* "D:Users\%%G\Desktop")
  FOR /f %%F in (%%G\Favorites) do (
   if exist %%F\*.* COPY 
   %%F\*.* "D:Users\%%G\Favorites")
 Popd )
```

I was hoping that the above code would loop through each of the users folder (found in documents and settings) and copy the subfolders 'Desktop' and 'Favorites' to a remote server with the same layout.  Right now I get errors saying the system cannot find the files.  However, simply replacing the 2 for loops with echo commands it will tell me it has correctly went through each user subfolder.  Then each for loop will copy stuff from a single folder to another single folder.  But when I try to combine them, it fails.

If there is an easier way to copy 2 subfolders from each user folder to a new location and keep them as subfolders of each user folder, I have no reason that it must be done in a batch file. I just don't have the time to manually go through each folder.  Copy Desktop and Favorites, move to the remote server, create that user folder, paste the desktop and favorites, and repeat for over 20 users.  Some of the users are much larger than others and manually moving them might take several hours.

This was my first post here, hopefully it was concise and clear.

Thank you all in advance, I have already gotten so much help from this site before I had this account.

Comment: `D:Users`? Is it just a mistake that you made when typing here or is it on the script itself?

Comment: Just a mistake typing on here.  I checked my scripts for any type errors.

Answer (score 0):

`FOR /R "C:\Documents and Settings\" %%G in (.) DO (` will loop through every folder (and subfolders) in `"C:\Documents and Settings\"`, but this script will then treat every single subfolder as a user's folder and attempt to copy the desktop and favourites from it, which is probably not what you want. The two `for` loops in the code are not really needed as well.

The following code uses `for /d`. `copy` is not really a good tool to use as it does not copy folders and other utilities should be used. Thus this code only copies files that are in the main folder and not in any subfolders.

```
 for /d %%G in ("C:\Documents and Settings\") do (
  if exist %%G\Desktop\*.* (
   copy %%G\Desktop\*.* "D:\Users\%%~nxG\Desktop"))
  if exist %%G\Favorites\*.* (
   copy %%G\Favorites\*.* "D:\Users\%%~nxG\Favorites"))
 )
```

Since `%%G` contains the absolute path, `%%~nxG` is to get only the name and extension of the folder (just in case the name has a `.` character in it) so that `"D:\Users\%%~nxG\Desktop"` will work. `pushd` and `popd` are also not needed as `%%G` contains the absolute path in this code.

Comment: Presumably there are folders on the desktop so xcopy or better Robocopy would suit to mirror the desktop etc.

Comment: I can't upvote your comment user2033427 but thank you!  I was looking for something like %%~nxG because I knew that the %%G was only reading the first string and some folder names do have a . or multiple spaces.  I see that a lot of the code I had wasn't needed but I'm not seeing code that is needed.  So I will use your answer along with foxidrive's suggestion and see what I can come up with.

Comment: So because I am on XP for now, the robust file copy won't work yet. But xcopy seems to be the best for this scenario.  using xcopy with the /EXCLUDE option can change this to one line.  All I have to do is say exclude the folders like [My Documents] [Local Settings] ect. and it will make a copy of the entire directory wherever I specify.  I can even use the /Z option since I will be copying to a remote server to ensure no temporary disconnects end the copying procedure.    Thanks all for your help.  should have looked more deeply into xcopy.  I never knew it had /Exclude

Comment: You should still be able to mark it as accepted :) I was too sleepy last night, but I was thinking of a `for /d /r` loop which would find all folders and subfolders, then make the corresponding directory on the other drive, and then copy the files over with `copy`.